# "On Error" send email and exit

Tags: bash, email, raspberry-pi

I have a script which at a certain time backs up files from one HD to another using a Raspberry Pi.

I need to start doing the rsyncs and if there is an error at any time, send the line number in an email then shutdown the pi.

But, I don't know how and where to add such a function in my existing script. Email is already set up to send messages to my domain.

```
    #!/bin/bash

begin=$(date --date="19:00" +%s)
end=$(date --date="21:00" +%s)
now=$(date +%s)

if [ "$begin" -le "$now" -a "$now" -le "$end" ]; then


    echo "/sbin/shutdown -h 15" | sudo at 20:40

else

begin=$(date --date="3:00" +%s)
end=$(date --date="6:00" +%s)
now=$(date +%s)

    if [ "$begin" -le "$now" -a "$now" -le "$end" ]; then

/usr/bin/rsync -avx --delete /media/HDD1/shares/myprofile /media/HDD2/shares/
/usr/bin/rsync -avx --delete /media/HDD1/shares/hanprofile /media/HDD2/shares/

else

echo "don't do rsyncs"

    fi

fi
```

Comment: You can send emails with a mail client.  Without knowing which ones are installed on your Rasberry Pi and without knowing what operating system it is using, anything more than quite vague advice is not possible

Comment: If you forego the requirement to report the line number, simply running your script from Cron will do almost exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the script add:

```
f () {
errcode=$? # save the exit code as the first thing done in the trap function

v1="Error "
v2=$errcode
v3=" the command executing at the time of the error was " 
v4=$BASH_COMMAND
v5=" on line "
v6=${BASH_LINENO[0]}
v7="$v1 $v2 $v3 $v4 $v5 $v6"

echo "$v7" | mail -s "Error" makem@myhome.co.uk
exit $errcode  # or use some other value or do return instead
}
trap f ERR
```